# Ubuntu 16.04 Cannot install libvirt-bin because of dependency errors

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

As the title suggests, I am currently pulling my hair over a dependency error on libvirt-bin. I need it to setup KVM for Android Emulation (learning to make apps for it) and I can't get libvirt-bin to install for the life of me. Here's the terminal output including me trying to go down the dependency rabbit hole:

```
kyle@kyle-EP43-UD3L:~$ sudo apt -f install libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libvirt-bin : Depends: libnetcf1 (>= 1:0.2.2) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. kyle@kyle-EP43-UD3L:~$ sudo apt install netcf Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  netcf : Depends: libnetcf1 (= 1:0.2.8-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. kyle@kyle-EP43-UD3L:~$ sudo apt install libnetcf1 Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libnetcf1 : Depends: libnl-route-3-200 (>= 3.2.7) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. kyle@kyle-EP43-UD3L:~$ sudo apt install libnl-route-3-200 Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libnl-route-3-200 : Depends: libnl-3-200 (= 3.2.27-1) but 3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. kyle@kyle-EP43-UD3L:~$ sudo apt install libnl-3-200 Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done libnl-3-200 is already the newest version (3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Basically, going down the list of dependencies that are not going to be installed, it seems to be because of lbnl-3-200 being an ubuntu version not the version that literally all the other libs want...

Any ideas how to fix this damn issue, I can't find anything on it online.

Answer (score 1):

Install `libvirt-bin` following the steps below:

1. Download [`libnl-route-3-200`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libnl-route-3-200/download).
2. Now similarly download [`libnetcf1`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libnetcf1/download) and [`libvirt-bin`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libvirt-bin/download). In a terminal change the working directory to the download directory and the run the commands:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libnl-route-3-200_3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb libnetcf1_0.2.8-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb libvirt-bin_1.3.1-1ubuntu10_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Use `sudo systemctl restart libvirt-bin.service` to restart the service.
4. Use `sudo systemctl status libvirt-bin.service` to see the `libvirt` status.

Answer (score -1):

I faced same issue.
Got resolved by adding xenial-updates and xenial-backports to the sources list.

Comment: Can you **[edit]** this answer to expand it with an explanation of how to do that?